# Conditional about a deceased person

Tags: conditionals

"Tom *would* know about the ledger" in this example the said person is deceased (not alive at the moment) so why can't we use *would have* in this sentence. Which is more grammatical?

Comment: "If Tom **were** alive he **would know** about the ledger **now**." "If Tom **had been** alive he **would have known** about the ledger **then**."

Comment: Also, *"If Tom* ***was*** *alive, he would know about the ledger now."*

Comment: It's correct grammatically. It's probably correct in the given context. Whether Tom be alive or not. They mean different things.

Comment: @StoneyB "Tom **would know** about the ledger" (of a now-decased Tom) would be very common and would make sense to anyone. It doesn't ring the same to say otherwise.

Comment: Funny that you should say 'not alive **at the moment**' XD

Answer (score 1):

"Tom would know about the ledger" -speaks to Tom's past knowledge or expertise

"Tom would have known about the ledger" -speaks to Tom's knowledge or expertise but subtly referencing his death -the fact that he is **now incapable** of knowing about the ledger

Answer (score 0):

"Tom knew about the ledger."  That work?

Comment: It doesn't really express the same counterfactual.

Comment: And it also might not be true, e.g. if the ledger being discussed didn't exist when Tom was alive, or he didn't know about it at the time.